# Piping data on Windows command prompt

Tags: svn, command-line, backup, svnadmin

I need to get a backup dump of a large (~8gb) svn repository. My current method involves using `svnadmin dump` to a file and then using 7-Zip to compress and split the file.

```
> svnadmin dump c:\path\to\myrepo > c:\svndump.svn
> 7z svndump.svn svndump.7z      // or whatever the correct syntax is
```

I was wondering if there would be a way to skip the middle-man here, and get the svn dump data to be compressed in one go by using pipes or something? Is this possible? What would the syntax be?

Comment: response to the close vote: ok, yes, not directly programming related, but tangentially so. Plus it has a definitive and authoritative answer, so I think it fits on Stack Overflow.

Comment: it's on topic - it relates to effective use of programming related tools

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`svnadmin dump` dumps to standard out by default](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) and the [`7z` command line can read from standard input using the `-si` switch](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/7z).

```
svnadmin dump c:\path\to\myrepo | 7z a -si svndump.7z
```

Comment: Bleh, you beat me by 10 seconds or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your sample was exactly what I was looking for, this is what I did as a complete solution to "dump" all my repositories. 
That solution dump all svn repositories to 7-zip file without uncompressed intermediate.

Put that batch file in your "repository root", e.g. m:\repositories\dump-all.bat

```
pushd %~dp0
SET SEVENZIP="c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx1 -si 
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR /a:d /b') DO svnadmin dump %%i | %SEVENZIP% ..\_svndump\%%i.dump.7z
```

And, start that batch like this if you need to run it in low priority, both process (7z + svnadmin) will take a lot of cpu

```
start /low m:\repositories\dump-all.bat
```

Notes: "pushd %~dp0" set the "current directory" to where the batch file is, instead of starting it in "c:\windows\system32" if you start it from explorer with "run as administrator".  It also works if the working folder is on another drive.
No need to type "m:" and "cd \repositories". if you start it from "c:" drive.