# 7z piping a svn dump doesn't seem to work

Tags: svn, 7zip

My question is relative to this post:
[Piping data on Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805706/piping-data-on-windows-command-prompt)

I tried to dump repositories through 7zip using the following command but i get an error:

> No such interface supported svnadmin: E720232: Can't write to stream:
>   The pipe is being closed.

I don't know how i made it work, but i was originaly able to pass it on through 7zip, but it doesn't work anymore. Here is the command line i use:

```
svnadmin dump "D:\Users Shared Folders\Repositories\APC10738\" | C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a -si "D:\svndumps\APC10738.zip"
```

I was originally able to pass it on to 7zip but the -tgzip switch didn't work. What i'd like is to gzip all this and then transfer it to my new linnux based server and restore it into my new svn server.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i found my paths a bit to long so i went in the environment variable manager and added the path to 7-zip and the path to svnadmin shortening my paths by a lot and suddenly everything works :S