# extract all files changed in a git commit

Tags: windows, git

I need to make a patch for someone (they are not using git) - a zip of the files changed by a commit.

I thought something like

git archive --format=zip commitguid > myfiles.zip

but this extracts the entire thing, not just the changed files. Is there any way to do this? 
And to make it more complicated - is there any way of doing this with multiple commits (yes I should have branched before making the changes but that's hindsight)

EDIT

Based on @Amber solution below I can do this in 2 steps in Git Bash for windows with 7Zip  installed in c:\data\progs.

```
git diff --name-only a-sha b-sha > tmp.txt
/C/data/progs/7za.exe a myzip.zip @tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only <oldsha> <newsha> | zip dest.zip -@
```

filling in the proper SHAs/refs. For instance, to create a zip of only the files that changed between the `master` and `feature` branches:

```
git diff --name-only master feature | zip dest.zip -@
```

Comment: Thanks Amber. Any ideas how to get this to work on windows with only 7-zip installed ? I'm trying (the 2nd half of your command) | /C/progs/7za.exe a myzip.zip -@ but get Error: Incorrect command line

Comment: You can do it in one step with the 7-zip `-si` flag: http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/7z and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805706/piping-data-on-windows-command-prompt

Comment: This is nice but can you explain the `-@` part?

Comment: @EricMORAND If a file list is specified as `-@`, `zip` takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

See also `git help format-patch`. It produces a diff patch of all changes in a commit along with commit author, date, message, and some nice diff stats. You could zip and send that.

Comment: only of use if they can use git I think??? I thought it generated a single file format

Comment: @Andiih, no, the patches produced can be applied by standard (POSIX) `patch` utility and don't require `git`.

Comment: sadly not standard to windows :-( I've now tagged it as such!

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to the question ([on github-gist](https://gist.github.com/rmkpatchaa/f5949c4564cd504f72f110e6cbbd015f), from user rmkpatchaa).
It doesn't require any external tools and is a one line command in a windows Git Bash window:

```
git archive --output=changes.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2 --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB)
```

It creates a standard zip archive with only the files changed between the two commits, no extra git stuff or anything, and doesn't require any extra tool on the receiving side.

Comment: Good option and can be applied on Windows systems without zip. But it would be great to elaborate in answer - what the purpose options "HEAD" and  "--diff-filter=ACMRTUXB"